# Facebook's PHP sdk stopped working for me

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

Since yesterday I stopped beeing able to use the facebook php sdk. My code simply stopped working. Tried every code snippet I could find, and even the http://net.tutsplus.com tutorial that used to work. I have tried to change secret and even creating a new app, but still nothing.

I get the permission request, the permission is listed on my account. If another user tries to use the app it also does not work.

Using js sdk i can see /me (name, etc) using php sdk I cannot.

Is anyone having the same problem?

[UPDATE]
tried to use horuko and the same files work ok there, so the problem must be from the php host. I tried 2 different servers (centos vps running kloxo) and neither worked. One of them had worked yesterday

[UPDATE 2/FIX]
The problem was a mix of old cookies and browser cache. The app never worked as it should on my host, only on localhost. The cache somehow made it look like it worked on the server.

The problem was curl_exec() not being run (even tho it was enabled) and my setup had warning reporting disabled.

Comment: have you tried using a different app_id?

Comment: yes, several. Since them I debug a little more and everything works if i use heroku hosting. Using one of the two hosts I own does not work. Both have centos 5 running kloxo

Comment: You can also setup application on local 127.0.0.1 .

Answer (score 0):

My PHP SDK for Facebook is still working and I followed the guidelines of a more recent tutorial over at, http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Maybe this will help.

Comment: tried that sample and still does not work. oh, im using a canvas app